# PHP - Add value for each array in a 2D array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I don't really know how to explain what I would like to do, so here is an example. I have an 2D array, like this one :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [1] => value 1
        [2] => value 2
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [1] => value 1
        [2] => value 2
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [1] => value 1
        [2] => value 2
    )

)
```

And I would like to have this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [1] => value 1
        [2] => value 2
        [3] => value 3
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [1] => value 1
        [2] => value 2
        [3] => value 3
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [1] => value 1
        [2] => value 2
        [3] => value 3
    )

)
```

Can someone help me ? Thanks very much.

Comment: `$addElement = 'value 3'; array_walk($myArray, function(&$value) use ($addElement) { $value[] = $addElement; });`

Comment: `foreach($array as &$val) { $val[] = 'value 3'; }`

Comment: thanks @AbraCadaver !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop it and make sure to reference `&` the `$val` to update the original array. Then just append the new item:

```
foreach($array as &$val) {
    $val[] = 'value 3';
}
```

The other way:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $array[$key][] = 'value 3';
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer. I tried it but without the '&'.

Comment: Edited in the other way, but `$val` isn't used.